# substrings in lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have many log files

```
workstation_2020_10_30-230600.log
workstation_2020_11_01-143352.log
workstation_2020_11_02-123203.log
workstation_2020_11_02-181803.log
workstation_2020_11_02-194433.log
workstation_2020_11_02-203701.log
```

with lines like this

```
I 06Nov20 13:48:11.838: PrintConsole    PrintConsole(1) unknown 0   2386    ExposureStatusChanged: ExposureId=2386,ExposureName=foobar.tif,ExposureStatus=Successful,PercentComplete=100,GroupingCount=30,OrderingTimeout=0,IsComplete=True
```

I want to inspect all lines where the substring `IsComplete=True` is found to extract the timestamp and the name of the exposure file (stated after `ExposureName=`).

For the above example, the output should look like

```
06Nov20 13:48:11 foobar.tif
```

My best result is

```
cat workstation/* | grep tif.*IsComplete=True | cut -d '=' -f 3 | cut -d ',' -f 1 | sort


foobar.tif
foobar2.tif
foobar3.tif
...
```

which doesn't give me the timestamp. I don't know how to proceed easily without writing loops and functions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU `awk` for the third argument to `match()`, the following program comes to mind:

```
awk '/IsComplete=True/{match($0,"ExposureName=([^,]+)",a); print $2,$3,a[1]}' *.log
```

This will match all lines containing the string `IsComplete=True` and extract the pattern "`ExposureName=`, followed by any characters that are not the `,`", and place the latter part (which is the filename) in a capture group that will be stored in the array variable `a`.

It will then print the second and third "word" (space-separated field) which contain date and time, and then the content of the capture group from the `match()` call.

For your example, I get

```
06Nov20 13:48:11.838: foobar.tif
```

If you want to get rid of the ms-part of the timestamp, you can use `gensub()` to modify that field:

```
awk '/IsComplete=True/{match($0,"ExposureName=([^,]+)",a); print $2,gensub(/\..*$/,"","1",$3),a[1]}' *.log
```

Please be aware that the numbering of the fields (`$2`, `$3`) depends strongly on the presence/absence of spaces, because this is how `awk` splits a line into fields by default; so if the timestamp format were ever to change (e.g. to `06 Nov 20`), you would need to adapt the syntax in the `print` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm not very familiar with shell script. I was pretty sure there was a short solution with awk.

Comment: @XavierLambros No problem, glad it worked for you. Please be aware that the numbering of the fields (`$2`, `$3`) depends strongly on the presence/absence of spaces, because this is how `awk` splits a line into fields by default; so if the timestamp format were ever to change (e.g. to `06 Nov 20`), you would need to adapt the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E '/IsComplete=True/{
     s/^[^ ]* ([^.]*)\..*ExposureName=([^,]*),.*/\1 \2/;
}' *.log
```

Comment: Ok I took a while to understand the regex, I think I've got it. I definitly need to work on that, true power. Thank you for answering.